# Same code two results

Tags: php, logic

I'm having a wee bit of issues with some logic that works fine for one set of parameters but not for another.

The code I have is

```
$data = simplexml_load_file("http://api.fantasyfootballnerd.com/ffnScheduleXML.php?apiKey={Your key here}");

$date = 1;
$dateTest = 0;
$gameTimeTest = 0;
$gameTime = 1;
foreach($data->Schedule->Game as $game)
{

    if($game->attributes()->Week == $_GET['week'])
    {

        if($date==$dateTest)
        {
            echo "\r"; 
        }else {
            echo date('l, F jS', strtotime($date))."\r\n";
        }

        if ($gameTimeTest==$gameTime)
        {    
            echo "\r"; 
        } else{
            echo date("g:i A",strtotime($gameTime));    
        }
        $gameTimeTest = $gameTime;
        $dateTest = $date;
        echo  $game->attributes()->AwayTeam." at ".$game->attributes()->HomeTeam."\r\n";

        $date = $game->attributes()->GameDate;
        $gameTime = $game->attributes()->GameDate.' '.$game->attributes()->GameTime;

    }   
}
```

Now the part that checks the time works like it should, but the date part constantly spits out the date no matter what.

Comment: Can you post a sample of what the XML looks like?

Comment: What do you mean by _the date constantly spits out the date_?

Comment: @Havelock He assigns `$date` and `$dateTest` at the bottom of the loop.

Comment: @Stobor Here you go http://pastebin.com/MfJ8scTT

Comment: @Havelock : Sorry the date part. Basically I need to iterate through the XML for the given week, check if the date for the current game is the same as the last one in the loop, and if not I need to echo out the date.